# Why is the need for Java NIOs

Tags: java, nio

I want to know what was the most promising feature delivered as part of Java NIOs which was not present in the earlier normal IOs. I know the following differences already:

```
Java IO         | Java NIOs
Stream oriented | Buffer oriented
Blocking IO     | Non blocking IO
                  Selectors
```

Java NIOs greatly simplifies life in handling multiple read/write threads at the same time but let say if i had multiple CPUs/huge CPU power, then what's the advantage of NIOs over normal IOs. It was asked in one of the interview and i tried explaining it using above points but the answer didn't seem satisfactory to him.

Comment: try reading http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html (first google hit on "Java nio vs io")

Comment: I have read through those tutorials already. doesn't seem to find the answer to above question. :(

Comment: guys, i seriously don't understand why some people are voting negative for the question..If there is something wrong, why don't you tell me

Comment: why the down vote: monkeys say hoot.  sometimes down votes don't make sense because even monkeys can vote and the voting system on stackoverflow (and most sites) is a beauty contest not a meritocracy

Comment: Short answer of Why NIO: asynchronous IO has significant advantages over synchronous IO and NIO introduced asynchronous IO.

Comment: @DwB up vote for the apt analogy ;-)

Comment: Only the interviewer can know what the interviewer wanted to hear. Ask him. But you've named all the salient features except for direct buffers, and if he considers those to be significantly more important than what you've named he is probably wrong. You might consider it a bullet dodged. Working for people with idiosyncratically wrong ideas is no fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table below summarizes the main differences between Java NIO and IO. I will get into more detail about each difference in the sections following the table.
IO is Stream oriented and Blocking IO ,NIO is  Buffer oriented and Non blocking IO

Stream Oriented vs. Buffer Oriented

The first big difference between Java NIO and IO is that IO is stream oriented, where NIO is buffer oriented. So, what does that mean?

Java IO being stream oriented means that you read one or more bytes at a time, from a stream. What you do with the read bytes is up to you. They are not cached anywhere. Furthermore, you cannot move forth and back in the data in a stream. If you need to move forth and back in the data read from a stream, you will need to cache it in a buffer first.

Java NIO's buffer oriented approach is slightly different. Data is read into a buffer from which it is later processed. You can move forth and back in the buffer as you need to. This gives you a bit more flexibility during processing. However, you also need to check if the buffer contains all the data you need in order to fully process it. And, you need to make sure that when reading more data into the buffer, you do not overwrite data in the buffer you have not yet processed.
Blocking vs. Non-blocking IO

Java IO's various streams are blocking. That means, that when a thread invokes a read() or write(), that thread is blocked until there is some data to read, or the data is fully written. The thread can do nothing else in the meantime.

Java NIO's non-blocking mode enables a thread to request reading data from a channel, and only get what is currently available, or nothing at all, if no data is currently available. Rather than remain blocked until data becomes available for reading, the thread can go on with something else.

The same is true for non-blocking writing. A thread can request that some data be written to a channel, but not wait for it to be fully written. The thread can then go on and do something else in the mean time.

What threads spend their idle time on when not blocked in IO calls, is usually performing IO on other channels in the meantime. That is, a single thread can now manage multiple channels of input and output.
Selectors

Java NIO's selectors allow a single thread to monitor multiple channels of input. You can register multiple channels with a selector, then use a single thread to "select" the channels that have input available for processing, or select the channels that are ready for writing. This selector mechanism makes it easy for a single thread to manage multiple channels.

Comment: I already know all the points explained by you. I even told these points to the interviewer, but he didn't seem happy with answer. he was looking for something else

Answer (score 1):

Great advantage of **Java NIO**

- Java NIO: A single thread managing multiple connections. where as
- Java IO: A classic IO server design - one connection handled by one thread.Source [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably just some *key words* were wanted: memory mapped files, non-blocking I/O & timeouts, listeners, multiple channels by selector.

Comment: I told all of these. I use NIOs extensively in my current project.